# Gmap.net Error in WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls, gmap.net

After adding the reference component in the Toolbox, the following error occurs when trying to use the component:

"**A reference to "GMap.Net.WindowsPresentation,Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b8b9027b614afef" has been added to the project. In rder to use
types from the new reference,press OK to restart the XAML designer. After the XAML Designer restarts, re-create the control on the artboard.**"

Already restarted Visual Studio, but not resolved.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information.. You did add the Gmap.Net.WindowsPresentation DLL to you Toolbox? And then it tells you to restart..? Maybe some code or explainary images would be nice.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk i tested it on a new application, there is no code unless InitializeComponent ().

Comment: is the GMapControl (dll) you are adding to your toolbox an WPF control? or is is winforms. That can maybe explain why you cant drop it on the view.

Comment: but which dll are you referencing for the toolbox? you need to have the one on this site (http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/20235) the Windows Presentation Foundation one not the winforms one.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

1. Use Windows Explorer to find GMap.NET.Core.dll and GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll
2. Right click
3. Select Properties
4. Click the Unblock button