# VS WPF Designer: how to add control from referenced project to a form in the main project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, designer

I have a very simple two-project solution in Visual Studio 2015 Community.  One project is a WPF application; the other is a class library.  I have added a project reference in the main project to the class library.  The class library contains one WPF UserControl named `TestControl` with the following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeControls.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,102,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="121" Width="164"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The only controls it contains are standard WPF controls.

The class library project builds successfully, and when I open the WPF designer for the main window in the WPF Application project, the `TestControl` control from the class library appears in the Toolbox.  But when I select that control from the Toolbox and try to add an instance to my main window, I get a dialog that states:

> The following reference has been added to the project:
>
> "SomeControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
>
> In order to use types from the new reference, press OK to restart the
>   XAML Designer.  After the XAML Designer restarts, re-create the
>   control on the artboard.

When I click "OK," nothing changes, and if I try to add the control again, I get the same error dialog.  I have tried closing and re-opening the XAML file as well as closing and re-opening Visual Studio.

Why won't Visual Studio let me add a control from a referenced project via the designer?

Here is a screenshot showing my setup and the dialog I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should try to add `xmlns:other="clr-namespace:SomeControls"` and calling `<other:TestControl />`

Answer (score 2):

Clear everything related with custom control currently. Drag the DLL directly to the Toolbox, no need to add the reference seperately. This dragging operation makes everything you need. It adds the DLL as reference, the xmlns namespace and the assembly name automatically.

I tested it using your code and it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Gmap.net Error in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916092/gmap-net-error-in-wpf)

Clear everything related with your DLL in reference and toolbox. Close the VS and then :

1. Find your dll file (via windows explorer or etc)
2. Right click on it
3. Select properties
4. Click the unblock button and apply and ok.

Answer (score 0):

1.Select "SomeControls" in "Reference, and set "Copy Local" to true.

2.Then build your "wpfApplication1"